# How can I add custom lifecycle in Apache Maven IDE Integration?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I want to add an custom lifecycle.How can I add custom lifecycle in Apache Maven IDE Integration?
[pulgin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR0Rk.png)

Comment: Which custom lifecycle? And which IDE ?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA,Maven Integration version is 172.3757.52

Comment: If you like to add a custom life cycle to your IDE you need to search for IDEA related areas to ask for...If you like to do that in Maven the question will come up: Why ? And what for?

Answer (score 0):

It's a reasonable question. The real [Maven lifeycle has 20+ phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), IntelliJ is only showing the most "popular" handful of them.

Simply uncheck the 'Show Basic Phases Only' option. It's available in the menu shown by clicking the gear icon in the top right.  Once you see all the phases, you can do whatever you want.

It's not an easy configuration option to find or stumble upon.